# Mapping Java ArrayList<CustomClass> and Flex ArrayCollection

Tags: java, apache-flex, arrays, actionscript, lcds

I'm currently trying to map a java ArrayList with a Flex ArrayCollection, through LCDS.
My Flex application does call the Java method that returns the ArrayList, but I haven't managed to retrieve the ArrayList to display it in a DataGrid, on Flex side.

JavaSide:
I have 2 classes:
 - Jco_test.java: it contains the method public ArrayList all()
 - Customclass.java: it contains a constructor that initializes some variables

```
    public class CustomClass {

    String airline;
    String cityFrom;
    String cityTo;
    Date flightDate;
    BigDecimal price;

    public CustomClass(String s1, String s2, String s3, Date d, BigDecimal bd){
        airline = s1;
        cityFrom = s2;
        cityTo = s3;
        flightDate = d;
        price = bd;
    }    
}
```

FlexSide:

- test.mxml:

  ```
          import mx.messaging.AbstractConsumer;
          import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
          import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
          import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
          import mx.controls.Alert;

      public var flightList:ArrayCollection;

      public function ResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
          flightList = (event.result as ArrayCollection);             
      }

      public function FaultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void{
          flightList = new ArrayCollection();
          ta.text = "Error id: " + event.fault.errorID + "\n";
          ta.text += "String: " + event.fault.faultString + "\n";
          ta.text += "Code: " + event.fault.faultCode + "\n";
          ta.text += "Detail: " + event.fault.faultDetail + "\n";
          ta.text += "Stack: \n" + event.fault.getStackTrace() + "\n";
      }
  ```

RemoteObject id="ro" destination="jco" result="ResultHandler(event);" fault="FaultHandler(event);"

```
    <mx:Panel title="monTest" width="699" height="549" x="10">
        <mx:Button label="go" click="ro.all();"/>
        <mx:DataGrid dataProvider="flightList">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="AIRLINE" headerText="Airline" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="CITYFROM" headerText="From" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="CITYTO" headerText="To" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="FLIGHTDATE" headerText="Date" />
                <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="PRICE" headerText="Price" />
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:DataGrid>
        <mx:TextArea id="ta" width="100%" height="219"/>    
    </mx:Panel>
```

- CustomClass.as:

  ```
  [Bindable]
  [RemoteClass(alias="utils.CustomClass")]
  public class CustomClass{
      public var airline:String;
      public var cityFrom:String;
      public var cityTo:String;
      public var flightDate:Date;
      public var price:String;       
  }
  ```

Am I doing something wrong? 
I still have some doubts... My ArrayList does not have headers. How can I retrieve the data in my DataGridColumn?

Thanks for any help you can provide.
Regards.

(Sorry about the formatting issues...)

---

I had indeed forgotten the getter and the setters. 
Now, I can see in the server log the values I was looking for. But Flex is still not able to display the Data.

Here is the log:

```
[LCDS]Adapter 'java-object' called 'com.alti.jco.jco_test.all(java.util.Arrays$A
rrayList (Collection size:0)
)'
[LCDS]Result: 'java.util.ArrayList (Collection size:3)
  [0] = utils.CustomClass
    cityTo = aa
    price = 30
    cityFrom = aa
    flightDate = Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 CET 1913
    airline = aa

  [1] = utils.CustomClass
    cityTo = bb
    price = 30
    cityFrom = bb
    flightDate = Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 CET 1913
    airline = bb

  [2] = utils.CustomClass
    cityTo = cc
    price = 30
    cityFrom = cc
    flightDate = Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 CET 1913
    airline = cc

'
[LCDS]Serializing AMF/HTTP response
Version: 3
  (Message #0 targetURI=/2/onResult, responseURI=)
    (Externalizable Object #0 'DSK')
      (Externalizable Object #1 'flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection')
        (Array #2)
          [0] = (Typed Object #3 'utils.CustomClass')
            cityTo = "aa"
            price = "30"
            cityFrom = "aa"
            flightDate = Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 CET 1913
            airline = "aa"
          [1] = (Typed Object #5 'utils.CustomClass')
            cityTo = "bb"
            price = "30"
            cityFrom = "bb"
            flightDate = (Ref #4)
            airline = "bb"
          [2] = (Typed Object #6 'utils.CustomClass')
            cityTo = "cc"
            price = "30"
            cityFrom = "cc"
            flightDate = (Ref #4)
            airline = "cc"
1.254745294734E12
(Byte Array #7, Length 16)
(Byte Array #8, Length 16)
(Byte Array #9, Length 16)
```

I'm not sure about the DataGridColumn's datafield case sensitivity, so I changed the datafields to match each field.

Comment: Do you really have caps in the dataField, or are they typos?

Comment: Please edit the post to rectify the code formatting. And btw, is the dataField AIRLINE or airLine?

Comment: @bug-a-lot: I wasn' sure if the datafield were case sensitives. I changed the caps so that I matches the fields in my Java class.

@Amarghogh: Sorry for the formatting, but I had issues formatting my code... Don't know why, sometimes, my text just does not want to format... 
I now changed the dataField, it is now airline (like in the java and actionscript classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issues =)
I had a binding mistake.

My dataGrid was using "flightList" as the dataProvider, but I did not define it as a Bindable variable.

Thanks a lot for your answers =)

Answer (score 1):

1 observation

add getter and setter in CustomClass.java